Get ETH transfers of several addresses from Etherscan
I am trying to get the data about ETH transfers from multiple addresses on Etherscan, similar to what I can find on https://etherscan.io/tokentxns. This is so I can track how much ETH an address has invested in a specific protocol like Notional Finance v2. I appreciate your help!

check duneanalytics website, maybe it will help

You can do that by for example using the Etherscan API, more specifically the accounts endpoint to fetch data about transactions per account/address.
https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts
Via this endpoint you can fetch data per account  that retrieves a transaction list. You need to enter your API key and the address you want to search for.
https://api.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=account
   &action=txlist
   &address=0xc5102fE9359FD9a28f877a67E36B0F050d81a3CC
   &startblock=0
   &endblock=99999999
   &page=1
   &offset=10
   &sort=asc
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken

PLEASE NOTE what is written in the docs for this endpoint:

Returns the list of transactions performed by an address, with optional pagination. This API endpoint returns a maximum of 10000 records only.

From there you can filter the transactions that interacted with the contract you are looking for. Filter the to parameter by the contract address you are looking for.
If you want to do that for multiple addresses, you can write a script that does that for you, by looping through these addresses. Here a simple javascript example to fetch this data.
const axios = require('axios');

const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
// Replace with the list of addresses
const addresses = ['0xAddress1', '0xAddress2'];  
// Replace with desired contract address
const protocolContract = 'ContractAddress';  



async function fetchTransactions(address) {
    
    try {
        // define url to your needs
        const url = https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xc5102fE9359FD9a28f877a67E36B0F050d81a3CC&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data.result.filter(tx => tx.to.toLowerCase() === protocolContract.toLowerCase());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching tx for ${address}:`, error);
        return [];
    }
}

async function trackInvestments() {
    for (let address of addresses) {
        const transactions = await fetchTransactions(address);
        console.log(`Tx for ${address} with ${protocolContract}:`, transactions);
    }
}

trackInvestments();

Then you need to rewrite the script to do whatevery you want to do with it.
